# How can I replicate the Netflix jawbone animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In Netflix, when you hover over a movie thumbnail in a specific row, the thumbnail scales in size a bit, and you get an option to dropdown and open a separate component which they've labeled `.jawbone`.

When this `.jawbone` is opened, all of the rows of movies below the `.jawbone` are moved downwards using `translate3d` in CSS.

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate they're doing this.

I can see that all the rows below (once the `.jawbone` is open), have a media query of `max-width` and `min-width` applied to them, which then activates the `transform: translate3d()`, but how are they only applying this media query to the rows **below**, and not the rows **above** the movie row with the `.jawbone` open?

Comment: Try setting the [Attributes modification](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom) breakpoint in devtools, and then clicking on the row any changes to the CSS styles of the elements will cause the debugger to stop. I personally do not use Netflix, so cannot test it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

All the rows have a common class for eg: rowContainer applied to them.

When a particular thumbnail is hovered and it's preview is opened then apply a unique class for eg: rowContainerPreviewOpen to the row where this thumbnail belongs to.

After this, use the following selector in your .css file.

```
.rowContainer.rowContainerPreviewOpen ~ .rowContainer {
   transform: translate3d(0, <desired pixel value>px, 0);
 }
```

The ~ means that apply the transform to all the rows after the current previewing row.